# How to Custom Search Panel In jQGrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

How Custom Search Panel In jQgrid example I Want translate search operation example equal to = or greaderthen > or ... or translate to arabic,

thanks all

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have perused the jqGrid wiki and found two pages which might help you.

1. [This page](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acustom_searching) talks about custom searching and its parameters. Notice that you can bind to the *beforeSearch* event and fire your own function, and parse the search text to accomplish whatever you want.
2. There is also [toolbar searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3atoolbar_searching&s%5B%5D=search), which allows custom filtering on each field in your data table. Depending on your solution, you may want to pursue this path. Again, this option also has events that you can bind to if the default search options don't fit your need.